# randomly assigning objects to a grid using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, random

I am trying to create a 10x10 grid of circles and squares, in which the placement of objects is assigned at random.

For instance, the following code creates a 10x10 grid with 80% circles and 20% squares, but the placement is not random:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}{
    \foreach \y in {3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}{
    \begin{scope}[shift={(2*\x,2*\y)}]
      \node[circle,draw,minimum size =1.25cm,fill=black] (c) at (0,0){};
    \end{scope}
    }
  }
  \foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}{
    \foreach \y in {1,2}{
    \begin{scope}[shift={(2*\x,2*\y)}]
      \node[rectangle,draw,minimum size =1.25cm,fill=black] (c) at (0,0){};
    \end{scope}
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the image looks like:

[image]

Is it possible to have tikz randomly assign the placement of the objects/nodes?

Comment: You may be interested in an old blog post on this: https://tex-talk.net/2011/08/do-the-knuth-shuffle/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE. There are various possibilities, among which `\pgfmathrandom` and the convenient (`\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist`, `\pgfmathrandomitem`) pair. Here is a solution using the latter:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{shapes}{{circle}{rectangle}}
  \foreach \x in {1,...,10} {
    \foreach \y in {1,...,10} {
      \pgfmathrandomitem{\myShape}{shapes}
      \node[\myShape, draw, minimum size=1.25cm, fill=black] at (2*\x,2*\y) {};
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the code for the various pictures were more difficult to factor, you could, using the same technique, randomly select between, e.g., `\macroA` and `\macroB`:

```
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{mymacros}{{\macroA}{\macroB}}

...

\pgfmathrandomitem{\randMacro}{mymacros}
\randMacro
```

## Keeping a fixed proportion between circles and rectangles

According to your comments, we'll now focus on obtaining 80 % of circles and 20 % of rectangles.

### Probabilistic approach

In this approach, each time we add an item to the “canvas”, its shape is randomly chosen with a probability of 0.8 for a circle and 0.2 for a rectangle. In these conditions, when drawing 100 items, the number of circles can be any number between 0 and 100 (both inclusive; the number of circles obtained follows a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with parameters *n* = 100 and *p* = 0.8).

In order to implement this, you could reuse the previous technique with an input list containing for instance four `circle` elements and one `rectangle` element. Here is another way using `random()` (i.e., `\pgfmathrandom`) which returns a random floating point number between 0 and 1 (with a uniform distribution):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{shapes}{{circle}{rectangle}}
  \foreach \x in {1,...,10} {
    \foreach \y in {1,...,10} {
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\myShape}{(random() < 0.8) ? "circle" : "rectangle"}
      \node[\myShape, draw, minimum size=1.25cm, fill=black] at (2*\x,2*\y) {};
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: the random seed appears to change every minute with this approach (tested with the pdfTeX engine). From the [Ti*k*Z and PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf):

[image]

### Exact approach

With the following code, if you draw 100 items, exactly 80 of them will be circles and 20 of them rectangles. This works by creating a list of 100 items (80 `circle` and 20 `rectangle` items), randomly shuffling this list then popping each item one by one.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% We need global assignments for this sequence because \foreach executes each
% iteration in its own group.
\seq_new:N \g_dave_shapes_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \dave_init_shapes:
  {
    \seq_gclear:N \g_dave_shapes_seq
    \int_step_inline:nn { 80 }
      { \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_dave_shapes_seq { circle } }
    \int_step_inline:nn { 20 }
      { \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_dave_shapes_seq { rectangle } }
    \seq_gshuffle:N \g_dave_shapes_seq
  }

\msg_new:nnn { dave } { no-more-items }
  { No~ more~ items~ in~ the~ \token_to_str:N #1 sequence. }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \dave_pop_one_shape:N #1
  {
    \seq_gpop_left:NN \g_dave_shapes_seq #1
    \quark_if_no_value:NT #1
      { \msg_error:nnn { dave } { no-more-items } { \g_dave_shapes_seq } }
  }

\cs_new_eq:NN \initShapes \dave_init_shapes:
\cs_new_eq:NN \popOneShape \dave_pop_one_shape:N

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \initShapes

  \foreach \x in {1,...,10} {
    \foreach \y in {1,...,10} {
      \popOneShape{\myShape}
      \node[\myShape, draw, minimum size=1.25cm, fill=black] at (2*\x,2*\y) {};
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, frougon! One follow-up question, which is my fault for not being more clear in my initial post. Is it possible to do the random assignment while keeping the proportions fixed, i.e., 20% squares and 80% circles?

Comment: Yes, please see the updated answer. The 80% / 20% distribution is probabilistic in my solution; for an exact count, a different way is needed. Do you need an exact 80% / 20 % count?

Comment: I've added code for the exact approach (80 / 20 counts guaranteed if you draw 100 items).

Comment: Thanks @frougon for your patience and help. Yeah I'm looking for something where you can specify the exact percentages, and where it will reshuffle the placement each time you compile/build.

Comment: Sorry I posted my last comment before seeing your last update. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Okay, no problem. :-)