# Randomly sampling a subset of images without replacement from a larger list of images

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, graphics, random

I am trying to create a 10x10 matrix of external images, where the placement is a given image is random and the selection of images are randomly sampled from a larger set of images.

Specifically, I have 4 sets E_1, E_2, E_3, E_4 of external images where each E_i has n_i elements. I have integers noted k_1, k_2, k_3, k_4 such that k_i ≤ n_i for each i in {1,..., 4}.

I want to obtain a set F containing N = k_1 + k_2 + k_3 + k_4 elements. More precisely, F should contain:

- k_1 randomly-selected, distinct elements from E_1;
- k_2 randomly-selected, distinct elements from E_2;
- k_3 randomly-selected, distinct elements from E_3;
- k_4 randomly-selected, distinct elements from E_4.

In other words, I’d like to randomly draw (without replacement) a subset of external images from each image set, and have those images randomly placed on the 10x10 matrix. At the same time, I want to be able to specify the exact proportion/number of images that are shown from each of the 4 sets.

Below is some code ([modified from a previous post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/651115/randomly-assigning-objects-to-a-grid-using-tikz?noredirect=1#comment1622822_651115)) that allows me to specify the exact proportions of each set (BM, WM, BF, WF) that are shown on the matrix while randomly shuffling the exact placement of each image. (In this example, BM populates 40% of the images, WM populates 10% of the images, BF populates 40% of the images, and WF populates 10% of the images).

However, this code only does so for one image per set. What I’d like to do is have a list of roughly 50 images per set, and then randomly sample a subset of those images (without repetitions of images).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% We need global assignments for this sequence because \foreach executes each
% iteration in its own group.
\seq_new:N \g_dave_Images_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \dave_init_Images:
  {
    \seq_gclear:N \g_dave_Images_seq
    \int_step_inline:nn { 40 }
      { \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_dave_Images_seq { BM-01.jpg } }
    \int_step_inline:nn { 10 }
      { \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_dave_Images_seq { WM-01.jpg } }
    \int_step_inline:nn { 10 }
      { \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_dave_Images_seq { WF-01.jpg } }
    \int_step_inline:nn { 40 }
      { \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_dave_Images_seq { BF-01.jpg } }
    \seq_gshuffle:N \g_dave_Images_seq
  }

\msg_new:nnn { dave } { no-more-items }
  { No~ more~ items~ in~ the~ \token_to_str:N #1 sequence. }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \dave_pop_one_Image:N #1
  {
    \seq_gpop_left:NN \g_dave_Images_seq #1
    \quark_if_no_value:NT #1
      { \msg_error:nnn { dave } { no-more-items } { \g_dave_Images_seq } }
  }

\cs_new_eq:NN \initImages \dave_init_Images:
\cs_new_eq:NN \popOneImage \dave_pop_one_Image:N

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \initImages

  \foreach \x in {1,...,10} {
    \foreach \y in {1,...,10} {
      \popOneImage{\myImage}
      \node[inner sep=2pt] at (2*\x,2*\y){\includegraphics[height=.15\textwidth]{\myImage}};
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks like you don't really like expl3 programming. I suggest just writing some Python code to generate the TikZ code that draws the desired figure.

Comment: To sample k random elements without repeat from a set of n elements, simply make a list of all n elements, shuffle it, then take the first k.

Comment: Maybe the question title could be shortened as “Random sampling from several sets with constraints” (the crux of the question is about data structures and algorithms; the use of Ti*k*Z and images is quite anectodal, IMHO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Full version with group attributes

The following is a generalization of the “basic version” from the next section. It is almost the same but makes the example more visual (small grid, geometric shapes, color) and adds support for an arbitrary number of per-group attributes (the example only sets one attribute named `node options` because this is the most convenient for its specific needs, but you can use as many as you want—see for instance the commented-out call to `\setGroupAttributesFromKeyval`).

This example produces two pictures (so you can see that redefining group contents is easy and can be done at any time). In the first picture:

- each color corresponds to one of the sets E_1, E_2, E_3, E_4;
- similarly, we use a distinct shape for each set;
- within each set, all items are uniquely numbered—so you can easily check that no item is ever reused.

16 items are placed in a 4×4 grid, respecting the following constraints:

- 5 unique blue items;
- 6 unique orange items;
- 2 unique “dark orchid“ items;
- 3 unique green items.

Sample output:

[image]

The second picture is very similar and shows how image inclusion can be done (there aren't many images in the `mwe` package that everyone has installed, hence the 3×3 grid):

[image]

Code producing both pictures:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% We use global assignments for these seq variables in order to make it easy
% to use the code given here with \foreach, which executes each iteration in
% its own _TeX group_.
\cs_new_protected:Npn \dave_group_new:n #1
  {
    \seq_new:c { g_dave_group_#1_seq }
    \prop_new:c { g_dave_group_#1_attributes_prop }
  }

% Set a metadata field (an “attribute”) for a group.
%
% #1: group name
% #2: attribute name (key)
% #3: value
\cs_new_protected:Npn \dave_group_set_attribute:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \prop_gput:cnn { g_dave_group_#1_attributes_prop } {#2} {#3}
  }

% Set all metadata fields (“attributes”) for a group at once.
%
% #1: group name
% #2: ⟨keyval list⟩, i.e. a comma list of the form
%     ⟨key1⟩ = ⟨value1⟩, ⟨key2⟩ = ⟨value2⟩, ...
%
% This *replaces all attributes* for the specified group. For details on the
% stripping of outer braces and trimming of outer spaces, see interface3.pdf.
\cs_new_protected:Npn \dave_group_set_attributes_from_keyval:nn #1#2
  {
    \prop_gset_from_keyval:cn { g_dave_group_#1_attributes_prop } {#2}
  }

% Retrieve a group attribute and store it in the specified macro or tl var.
%
% #1: macro or tl var where the result will be stored
% #2: group name
% #3: attribute name
\cs_new_protected:Npn \dave_group_set_to_attribute:Nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \prop_get:cnN { g_dave_group_#2_attributes_prop } {#3} #1
  }

% Expand to the value of the specified group attribute. This is slower than
% \dave_group_set_to_attribute:Nnn. The result is returned within the
% \unexpanded primitive (\exp_not:n).
%
% #1: group name
% #2: attribute name
\cs_new:Npn \dave_group_attribute:nn #1#2
  {
    \prop_item:cn { g_dave_group_#1_attributes_prop } {#2}
  }

\msg_new:nnn { dave } { attempt-to-set-undefined-group }
  { Trying~ to~ set~ group~ '#1',~ however~ it~ hasn't~ been~ defined~ yet. }

% Define the contents (i.e. all elements) of a group. Can be used several
% times for the same group (the last call overrides any previous calls).
%
% #1: name of the group
% #2: comma list of elements which determines the new contents of the group
\cs_new_protected:Npn \dave_group_set:nn #1#2
  {
    \seq_if_exist:cTF { g_dave_group_#1_seq }
      {
        \seq_gset_from_clist:cn { g_dave_group_#1_seq } {#2}
        \seq_gshuffle:c { g_dave_group_#1_seq }
      }
      { \msg_error:nnx { dave } { attempt-to-set-undefined-group } {#1} }
  }

\msg_new:nnn { dave } { no-more-items }
  { Not~ enough~ items~ in~ the~ '#1'~ group. }

% #1: macro or tl var where to store the popped element
% #2: name of the group to pop from
\cs_new_protected:Npn \dave_group_pop_one:Nn #1#2
  {
    \seq_gpop_left:cN { g_dave_group_#2_seq } #1
    \quark_if_no_value:NT #1 { \msg_error:nnx { dave } { no-more-items } {#2} }
  }

\msg_new:nnn { dave } { invalid-syntax-for-set-with-repeat-counts }
  {
    Invalid~ syntax~ for~ the~ following~ element~ of~ the~ first~ argument~
    of~ \exp_not:N \dave_group_set_with_repeat_counts:nn
    (\token_to_str:N \setGroupWithRepeatCounts):~ '#1'.
  }

\regex_const:Nn \c__dave_group_set_with_repeat_counts_regex
  { \A (.+) \: \h* (\d+) \Z }

% Define the contents of a group using repeat counts for each element.
%
% #1: group name
% #2: comma list of specifications of the form 'item: count' (see how
%     \setGroupWithRepeatCounts is used below)
\cs_new_protected:Npn \dave_group_set_with_repeat_counts:nn #1#2
  {
    \seq_if_exist:cTF { g_dave_group_#1_seq }
      { \__dave_group_set_with_repeat_counts:nn {#1} {#2} }
      { \msg_error:nnx { dave } { attempt-to-set-undefined-group } {#1} }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__dave_group_set_with_repeat_counts:nn #1#2
  {
    \seq_gclear:c { g_dave_group_#1_seq }

    \clist_map_inline:nn {#2}
      {
        \regex_extract_once:NnNTF \c__dave_group_set_with_repeat_counts_regex
          {##1} \l_tmpa_seq
          {
            \int_step_inline:nn { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 3 } }
              {
                \seq_gput_right:cx { g_dave_group_#1_seq }
                  { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 2 } }
              }
          }
          {
            \msg_error:nnn { dave }
              { invalid-syntax-for-set-with-repeat-counts } {##1}
          }
      }

    \seq_gshuffle:c { g_dave_group_#1_seq }
  }

\cs_new_eq:NN \newGroup \dave_group_new:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \setGroup \dave_group_set:nn
\cs_new_eq:NN \setGroupAttribute \dave_group_set_attribute:nnn
\cs_new_eq:NN \setGroupAttributesFromKeyval
              \dave_group_set_attributes_from_keyval:nn
\cs_new_eq:NN \setToGroupAttribute \dave_group_set_to_attribute:Nnn
\cs_new_eq:NN \groupAttribute \dave_group_attribute:nn
\cs_new_eq:NN \popOneFromGroup \dave_group_pop_one:Nn
\cs_new_eq:NN \setGroupWithRepeatCounts \dave_group_set_with_repeat_counts:nn

\ExplSyntaxOff

% Declare a few groups and assign them attributes. Alternatively, this could be
% done in the document body if you prefer.
\foreach \group in {high level, group 1, group 2, group 3, group 4}{%
  \newGroup{\group}%
}

\setGroupAttribute{group 1}{node options}{shape=circle, fill=DeepSkyBlue}
\setGroupAttribute{group 2}{node options}{shape=rectangle, fill=DarkOrange}
\setGroupAttribute{group 3}{node options}{shape=diamond, fill=DarkOrchid}
% The space tokens will be in the 'node options' attribute, however this
% doesn't matter because the value will be fed to \pgfkeys via \node. You can
% see why I used only one attribute to store all the node options pertaining
% to a group.
\setGroupAttribute{group 4}{node options}{
  shape=regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5, fill=MediumAquamarine,
}

% One can also set all attributes at once. Note that this *replaces all
% attributes* for the specified group.
% \setGroupAttributesFromKeyval{group 1}{attr1=value1, attr2=value2, ...}

\tikzset{style/.style={#1}}% trick from Qrrbrbirlbel (I don't remember where!)

\begin{document}

% ****************************************************************************
% *                              First picture                               *
% ****************************************************************************

% Contents of the 'high level' group
\setGroupWithRepeatCounts{high level}{%
  group 1: 5,     % 'group 1' is repeated five times
  group 2: 6,     % 'group 2' is repeated six times
  group 3: 2,     % 'group 3' is repeated twice
  group 4: 3      % 'group 4' is repeated three times
}

% Contents of the groups 'group 1', 'group 2', 'group 3' and 'group 4'
\setGroup{group 1}{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}% these groups aren't
\setGroup{group 2}{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}% required to have
\setGroup{group 3}{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}% the same number
\setGroup{group 4}{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}% of items

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {1,...,4} {
    \foreach \y in {1,...,4} {
      \popOneFromGroup{\lowLevelGroup}{high level}
      \popOneFromGroup{\chosenElement}{\lowLevelGroup}
      % Retrieve the value of the 'node options' attribute and store it in
      % \nodeOptions.
      \setToGroupAttribute{\nodeOptions}{\lowLevelGroup}{node options}
      \node[style/.expand once={\nodeOptions}, minimum size=1.25cm,
            text=white, font=\Large] at (1.5*\x, 1.5*\y) {\chosenElement};
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

% ****************************************************************************
% *                              Second picture                              *
% ****************************************************************************

% Redefine the contents of the 'high level' group
\setGroupWithRepeatCounts{high level}{%
  group 1: 2,     % 'group 1' is repeated twice
  group 2: 3,     % 'group 2' is repeated three times
  group 3: 2,     % 'group 3' is repeated twice
  group 4: 2      % 'group 4' is repeated twice
}

% Redefine the contents of groups 'group 1', 'group 2', 'group 3' and 'group 4'
\setGroup{group 1}{example-image, example-image-plain}
\setGroup{group 2}{example-image-a, example-image-b, example-image-c}
\setGroup{group 3}{example-image-duck, example-grid-100x100bp}
\setGroup{group 4}{example-image-4x3, example-image-golden}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
  \foreach \x in {1,...,3} {
    \foreach \y in {1,...,3} {
      \popOneFromGroup{\lowLevelGroup}{high level}
      \popOneFromGroup{\chosenElement}{\lowLevelGroup}
      % Retrieve the value of the 'node options' attribute and store it in
      % \nodeOptions.
      \setToGroupAttribute{\nodeOptions}{\lowLevelGroup}{node options}
      \node[style/.expand once={\nodeOptions}] at (\x, \y)
        {\includegraphics[height=1.25cm]{\chosenElement}};
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

## Basic version (no per-group attributes) with some explanations

What you're asking for can be done using the same approach as [before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/651120/73317), successively at two levels:

- from a `high_level` structure, you choose an item which identifies the set E_i you are going to draw from in the next step (i.e., in your example: randomly choose one of `BM`, `WM`, `WF`, `BF`, respecting the required proportions);
- from the randomly chosen set, you randomly choose an element (the name of an image in your case) and remove it from the set.

In the following code, I use the term “group”. This is neither the mathematical nor the TeX meaning of “group”. A *group* here is an `expl3` `seq` variable; you can think of it as list, except the order of elements used when you define the group doesn't matter. Repetitions are allowed, which I use to implement the count (or proportions) requirements for the high-level group—and that's enough of a reason why I don't call these “sets”.

As soon as my code *sets* a group (i.e., defines its contents), it shuffles it—that is why the order used in the second argument of `\setGroup` doesn't matter. Normally, the low-level groups `BM`, `WM`, `WF`, `BF` (corresponding to sets E_1, E_2, E_3, E_4 in your abstract description) will contain distinct elements, unless of course you want the same image to appear several times.

For ease of use, group names are recursively expanded by `\newGroup`, `\setGroup` and `\popOneFromGroup`. Don't put any formatting command (like `\textbf` or `\color`) in these names; they are simply identifiers like variable names in programming languages.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% We use global assignments for these seq variables in order to make it easy
% to use the code given here with \foreach, which executes each iteration in
% its own _TeX group_.
\cs_new_protected:Npn \dave_group_new:n #1
  {
    \seq_new:c { g_dave_group_#1_seq }
  }

\msg_new:nnn { dave } { attempt-to-set-undefined-group }
  { Trying~ to~ set~ group~ '#1',~ however~ it~ hasn't~ been~ defined~ yet. }

% Define the contents (i.e. all elements) of a group. Can be used several
% times for the same group (the last call overrides any previous calls).
%
% #1: name of the group
% #2: comma list of elements which determines the new contents of the group
\cs_new_protected:Npn \dave_group_set:nn #1#2
  {
    \seq_if_exist:cTF { g_dave_group_#1_seq }
      {
        \seq_gset_from_clist:cn { g_dave_group_#1_seq } {#2}
        \seq_gshuffle:c { g_dave_group_#1_seq }
      }
      { \msg_error:nnx { dave } { attempt-to-set-undefined-group } {#1} }
  }

\msg_new:nnn { dave } { no-more-items }
  { Not~ enough~ items~ in~ the~ '#1'~ group. }

% #1: macro or tl var where to store the popped element
% #2: name of the group to pop from
\cs_new_protected:Npn \dave_group_pop_one:Nn #1#2
  {
    \seq_gpop_left:cN { g_dave_group_#2_seq } #1
    \quark_if_no_value:NT #1 { \msg_error:nnx { dave } { no-more-items } {#2} }
  }


\msg_new:nnn { dave } { invalid-syntax-for-set-with-repeat-counts }
  {
    Invalid~ syntax~ for~ the~ following~ element~ of~ the~ first~ argument~
    of~ \exp_not:N \dave_group_set_with_repeat_counts:nn
    (\token_to_str:N \setGroupWithRepeatCounts):~ '#1'.
  }

\regex_const:Nn \c__dave_group_set_with_repeat_counts_regex
  { \A (.+) \: \h* (\d+) \Z }

% Define the contents of a group using repeat counts for each element.
%
% #1: group name
% #2: comma list of specifications of the form 'item: count' (see how
%     \setGroupWithRepeatCounts is used below)
\cs_new_protected:Npn \dave_group_set_with_repeat_counts:nn #1#2
  {
    \seq_if_exist:cTF { g_dave_group_#1_seq }
      { \__dave_group_set_with_repeat_counts:nn {#1} {#2} }
      { \msg_error:nnx { dave } { attempt-to-set-undefined-group } {#1} }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__dave_group_set_with_repeat_counts:nn #1#2
  {
    \seq_gclear:c { g_dave_group_#1_seq }

    \clist_map_inline:nn {#2}
      {
        \regex_extract_once:NnNTF \c__dave_group_set_with_repeat_counts_regex
          {##1} \l_tmpa_seq
          {
            \int_step_inline:nn { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 3 } }
              {
                \seq_gput_right:cx { g_dave_group_#1_seq }
                  { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 2 } }
              }
          }
          {
            \msg_error:nnn { dave }
              { invalid-syntax-for-set-with-repeat-counts } {##1}
          }
      }

    \seq_gshuffle:c { g_dave_group_#1_seq }
  }

\cs_new_eq:NN \newGroup \dave_group_new:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \setGroup \dave_group_set:nn
\cs_new_eq:NN \popOneFromGroup \dave_group_pop_one:Nn
\cs_new_eq:NN \setGroupWithRepeatCounts \dave_group_set_with_repeat_counts:nn

\ExplSyntaxOff

% Declare and populate the groups. Alternatively, this could be done in the
% document body if you prefer.
\foreach \group in {high level, BM, WM, WF, BF}{%
  \newGroup{\group}%
}

% Contents of the 'high level' group
\setGroupWithRepeatCounts{high level}{%
  BM: 40,     % 'BM' is repeated 40 times
  WM: 10,     % 'WM' is repeated 10 times
  WF: 10,     % 'WF' is repeated 10 times
  BF: 40      % 'BF' is repeated 40 times
}

% Contents of the four groups BM, WM, WF and BF. This could of course be
% automated; I'm doing it manually here, because this is where you'll want to
% put the names of your images.
\setGroup{BM}{BM-1, BM-2, BM-3, BM-4, BM-5, BM-6, BM-7, BM-8, BM-9, BM-10,
  BM-11, BM-12, BM-13, BM-14, BM-15, BM-16, BM-17, BM-18, BM-19, BM-20, BM-21,
  BM-22, BM-23, BM-24, BM-25, BM-26, BM-27, BM-28, BM-29, BM-30, BM-31, BM-32,
  BM-33, BM-34, BM-35, BM-36, BM-37, BM-38, BM-39, BM-40, BM-41, BM-42, BM-43,
  BM-44, BM-45, BM-46, BM-47, BM-48, BM-49, BM-50, BM-51}

\setGroup{WM}{WM-1, WM-2, WM-3, WM-4, WM-5, WM-6, WM-7, WM-8, WM-9, WM-10,
  WM-11, WM-12, WM-13, WM-14, WM-15, WM-16, WM-17, WM-18, WM-19, WM-20, WM-21,
  WM-22, WM-23, WM-24, WM-25, WM-26, WM-27, WM-28, WM-29, WM-30, WM-31, WM-32,
  WM-33, WM-34, WM-35, WM-36, WM-37, WM-38, WM-39, WM-40, WM-41, WM-42, WM-43,
  WM-44, WM-45, WM-46, WM-47, WM-48, WM-49, WM-50}

\setGroup{WF}{WF-1, WF-2, WF-3, WF-4, WF-5, WF-6, WF-7, WF-8, WF-9, WF-10,
  WF-11, WF-12, WF-13, WF-14, WF-15, WF-16, WF-17, WF-18, WF-19, WF-20, WF-21,
  WF-22, WF-23, WF-24, WF-25, WF-26, WF-27, WF-28, WF-29, WF-30, WF-31, WF-32,
  WF-33, WF-34, WF-35, WF-36, WF-37, WF-38, WF-39, WF-40, WF-41, WF-42, WF-43,
  WF-44, WF-45, WF-46, WF-47, WF-48}

\setGroup{BF}{BF-1, BF-2, BF-3, BF-4, BF-5, BF-6, BF-7, BF-8, BF-9, BF-10,
  BF-11, BF-12, BF-13, BF-14, BF-15, BF-16, BF-17, BF-18, BF-19, BF-20, BF-21,
  BF-22, BF-23, BF-24, BF-25, BF-26, BF-27, BF-28, BF-29, BF-30, BF-31, BF-32,
  BF-33, BF-34, BF-35, BF-36, BF-37, BF-38, BF-39, BF-40, BF-41, BF-42, BF-43,
  BF-44, BF-45, BF-46, BF-47, BF-48, BF-49, BF-50, BF-51, BF-52}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {1,...,10} {
    \foreach \y in {1,...,10} {
      \popOneFromGroup{\lowLevelGroup}{high level}
      \popOneFromGroup{\chosenElement}{\lowLevelGroup}
      \node[minimum size=1.25cm] at (1.5*\x, 1.5*\y) {\chosenElement};
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For your images: as shown in my first example, you can simply put their names instead of `BM-1`, `BM-2`, etc., and replace `\chosenElement` with an `\includegraphics{\chosenElement}` call in the node contents (don't forget to put `\usepackage{graphicx}` in the preamble).

Comment: As always, thank you for the extremely helpful and thorough response @frougon

Comment: Glad to hear that, thanks.